# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in views.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my applicaton when user fills inputs I should send him/her email and create instance of that user. But I can't run my application because of following error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/Users/progbash/Desktop/pragmatech/pragmatechproject/pragmatechproject/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('pragmatechapp.urls')),
  File "/Users/progbash/Desktop/pragmatech/denvx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/progbash/Desktop/pragmatech/denvx/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/progbash/Desktop/pragmatech/pragmatechproject/pragmatechapp/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/progbash/Desktop/pragmatech/pragmatechproject/pragmatechapp/views.py", line 26
    return render(request, 'pragmatechapp/index.html', context)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my `views.py`:

```
def index(request): 
    context = {
        'applicants': Applicant.objects.all()
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        applicant_name = request.POST.get('name')
        applicant_email = request.POST.get('email')
        applicant_phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        subject = 'Thank you.'
        message = 'Hi, ' + str(applicant_name)
        from_email = settings.SERVER_EMAIL
        recipient_list = [applicant_email]
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
        if request.POST.get('email'):
            Applicant.objects.create(
                name = request.POST.get('name'),
                email = request.POST.get('email'),
                phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

And my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this under typo/not reproducible, the only issue was a missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your this below section from index view...

Yor are missing to complete parenthesis over there...

```
if request.POST.get('email'):
        Applicant.objects.create(
            name = request.POST.get('name'),
            email = request.POST.get('email'),
            phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        )
```

Comment: Always... Happy Coding :)